# ATLANTBH jmeter-components: JSON Path Assertion

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonpath, jmeter-plugins

I'm trying to perform a JSON assertion using [ATLANTBH](https://github.com/ATLANTBH/jmeter-components) jmeter JSON PATH Assertion.
 However I cant seem to write a correct expression to get the following fields from the JSON feed posted below:

1. 123456789
2. 1009
3. SOME RANDOM MESSAGE

   ```
   {"api": {"status":"Success","callsremaining":36,"version":"x.x.x.x"}
   ,"result":{"errors":{"123456789":{"code":1009,"error":"SOME RANDOM MESSAGE"}}}
   }
   ```

Has anyone here got any experience using this JMeter plugin?
I know I could use `regex` and `Beanshell` to validate but I'd rather use these JSON Path Assertion.

Any help you could provide would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can easily assert both `1009` and `SOME RANDOM MESSAGE` values using JSONPath expressions (in JSON Path Assertion components) but not sure about `123456789`: that's not node value but bode name, and JSONPath implementation used by these components seems has no expressions to get node name.

Suppose you can easily use to assert `123456789` instead binding of JSON Path Extractor (from the same components collection) with jmeter's standard [Response_Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion).

1. Add 2 JSON Path Assertions as children to the sampler which returns json response you want to process:

   [image]

   [image]

   Expressions will be `$.result.errors..code` and `$.result.errors..error` correspondingly.
2. Add JSON Path Extractor as child to the same sampler to extract full error entry:

   [image]

   Expression: `$.result.errors.`.
   This will extract `{"123456789":{"error":"SOME RANDOM MESSAGE","code":1009}}` and save into the pointed variable (`${errorKey}`).
3. Add Response Assertion as child to the same sampler, after previously added JSON Path Extractor:

   [image]

   This will assert name of the key (`123456789`) in the value of `${errorKey}` variable.

---

So the final construction may look like

```
...
YOUR Sampler
    JSON Path Extractor
    JSON Path Assertion
    JSON Path Assertion
    Response Assertion
...
```