# How to parse out parameter names from json using regexp in JMeter?

Tags: regex, json, jmeter

I have several snippets in long common json, like in this piece (2 snippets):

```
"document.NAME1":{"name":"document.NAME1","result":[{"name":"**Patent**","count":54},{"name":"**Journal**","count":6}], ...},
"document.NAME2":{"name":"document.NAME2","result":[{"name":"**2013-12-01**","count":18},{"name":"**2012-12-09**","count":3},{"name":"**2012-12-06**","count":2}]
```

How should I write the regexp in JMeter in this case to get values like **Patent**, **Journal**,... for NAME1 and **2013-12-01**,**2012-12-09**,... for NAME2 from this json?

Comment: Just **don't use regex** to parse JSON. There are many JSON libaries available for Java.

Comment: @Bergi, And how can these libraries get me a parameters names from this json in JMeter?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use JSON-processing components from [Jmeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ExtrasWithLibsSet/), first of all [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/), with [JSONPath](http://code.google.com/p/json-path/) expressions:

- [ATLANTBH jmeter-components: JSON Path Assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072497/atlantbh-jmeter-components-json-path-assertion/15023517#15023517)
- [How to extract everything between 2 characters from JSON response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255956/how-to-extract-everything-between-2-characters-from-json-response/14262703#14262703)
- [Jmeter JSON Path Assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006542/jmeter-json-path-assertion/22016856#22016856)
- [Jmeter Xpath Extractor JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23929525/jmeter-xpath-extractor-json/23929851#23929851)
- [Need to extract data from this JSON in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864222/need-to-extract-data-from-this-json-in-jmeter/23869198#23869198)